# Export and Import select box options

Tags: script, automation

I have to fill out a web form choosing options from a select box for each question.. There 20 questions..

I Would like to answer one time and then save my choices because i have to do this multiple times.. Its possible to have the first choices replicate to another pages with the same questions and answers?

Maybe a Chrome or firefox plugin could help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found Google Extension - AUTO FILL does the work.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information? Where can you get the extension? How exactly did you get it to do what you needed? These details will help improve your answer.